# Why ruby constants are changable? What is the difference between variable?

Tags: ruby, constants

I was learning ruby, and i learnt that ruby constants must start with a Upper case letter (e.g. Myconstant). This will make it a constant, but its value is changeable!

If a constant's value is changeable then why do we need constant, what is the difference between variable then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants have lexical scoping, whereas methods have dynamic scoping:

```
class Super
  Constant = "Super::Constant"

  def method
    'Super#method'
  end

  def get_constant
    Constant
  end

  def get_method
    method
  end
end

class Sub < Super
  Constant = 'Sub::Constant'

  def method
    'Sub#method'
  end
end

Super.new.get_constant # => "Super::Constant"
Sub.new.get_constant   # => "Super::Constant"

Super.new.get_method # => "Super#method"
Sub.new.get_method   # => "Sub#method"
```

And as far as variables, they are inaccessible from the outside. How would you intend to access these?

```
class Object
  Constant      = 'constant'  
  local_var     = 'local var'
  @instance_var = 'instance var'
  @@class_var   = 'class var' # btw, never use these
end
```

Also, there's a lot of things you *can* do in Ruby, but for your own sanity, be wary. I'd recommend against changing constants around, it will likely frustrate your team.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation. Is there any reason why constant should be changeable? If its changeable, then why call it a constant (Name is ambiguous)?

Comment: I can't think of a particularly good one, but I also can't think of a reason to make it so you _can't_ change them. In general, they're constants because that's how we treat them, and they behave in a way that assumes this. But if you wound up in a situation where you needed to hack something, how frustrating would it be to have the language prevent you?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby lets you shoot yourself in the foot (if you really want to). But, at least in this case, it warns you about it.

```
ONE = 'one'
ONE = 'two' # !> already initialized constant ONE
```

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons:

1) Convention. It's easy to see just from the name of an identifier that it's not supposed to change.

2) Technical. It (probably; someone more knowledgeable than I will probably answer) makes the interpreter simpler.

3) Dynamism is sometimes helpful; in testing, for example, it's possible to redefine things for testing purposes rather than having to stub/proxy everything…

Answer (score 1):

I use this feature sometimes to test out code without otherwise necessary parameters, eg when i run the script from my editor where it is difficult to provide a parameter.

```
#ARGV[0] = "c:/test.txt"  #in case of testing i remove the first remark sign
```